# How to keep track of selected indexes (in array) in a UITableViewController Which contains another UITableView as its Cells

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

with the help of [THIS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2) . . . .

I made a UITableViewController (for reference I can call it MainTableVC)
, which has single row in each of its section
and 
I made every cell of this UITableViewController(MainTableVC) a UITableView (for reference I can call it UITableViewOfMainTableVCell) with many cells.

Now I rotated Cell/rows of UITableViewOfMainTableVCell {* its a UITableView not a UITableViewCell },
so that i could scroll cells of UITableViewOfMainTableVCell horizontally.

now my UI looks like this,
I have a table with 10 section(say), each section has one row/cell and in this row/cell i have several rows/cells which can be scrolled horizontally

I also enabled allowMultipleSelections in custom cells of UITableViewOfMainTableVCell

Now `I wanted to keep track of selected indexes of selected rows`
so 
I took an NSArray and saved indexPaths in it with this delegate method of UITableViewOfManiTableVCcells

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSMutableArray *selectedIndexesOfOneRow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]];
NSLog(@"number of selected Indexes = %d",[selectedIndexesOfOneRow count]);
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSMutableArray *selectedIndexesOfOneRow= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]];
NSLog(@"number of selected Indexes = %d",[selectedIndexesOfOneRow count]);
}
```

**MY PROBLEM** :-

suppose if I select 4 cells/rows in a row/cell of MainTableVC
the NSMutableArray *selectedIndexesOfOneRow has the right count
BUT
if I select cells of another a row in another section of MainTableVC with even keeping previous cells selected
the count starts from beginning

the problem is with indexPathsForSelectedRows,
it only keeps track of Selected Rows of single UITableView,
since i have separate UITableViews for each Row of Each Section of MainTableVC
NSMutableArray always gets reset when select cells from different row

**MY QUESTION**

since every Row/Cell calls the same UITableView delegate method, 
how will I prevent it, 
I want to store all the selected indexes of cells in whole UI

I could make an array of array to store indexes of different different indexes
but how would i get those differently

"HINT"
I could do somthing like this, 
in my MainTableVC, 
Since i have a tableView inside Cell of MainTableVC i can put an NSArray *array = [cell.tableView indexPathsOfSelectedIndex], but again in which delegate method of MainTableVC should i put this, and also i have checked, Since i am not selecting any whole row of MainTableVC(UITableViewController), its delegate methods didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath never get called

Comment: That tutorial you linked is 2 years old. Why the hell would you cause yourself such an unnecessary headache when you could use `UICollectionView`? The effort you're going to have to employ to maintain this setup is miles beyond what you would need to simply implement `UICollectionView`. Do yourself a massive favour and change your setup ASAP.

Comment: You can also check by if(indexPath.section==1){NSMutableArray *selectedIndexesOfOneRow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]];} else{NSMutableArray *selectedIndexesOfsecondRow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]];}

Comment: @GuyKogus : UICollectionView doesn't work for Xcode 4.0 i guess ??

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda : but in my UI only MainTableVC got Sections, and as i said each section has only single row, so i am not selecting any of these rows, instead of this i am selecting row's of the tableview which i got embedded inside Cells of MainTableVC.and it doesn't have sections. if i use indexpath,section isn't it gonna reset to 0 if i go to another tableView.

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda : I could do somthing like this,  in my MainTableVC, Since i have a tableView inside Cell of MainTableVC   i can put NSArray *array = [cell.tableView indexPathsOfSelectedIndex], but again in which delegate method of MainTableVC should i put this, and also i have checked, Since i am not selecting any whole row of MainTableVC(UITableViewController), its delegate methods didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath never get called

Comment: Look up PSTCollectionView. It's backwards compatible and highly recommended. Please, for the love of all that's good in the world of iOS development, don't do what you're doing! :)
(P.S. Of course you're free to do as you like, but it makes me cry.)

Answer (score 1):

You can assing tag to your tableView, then check tag to distinguish all tableView.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag==1) {
        //Do what ever you want with table having tab =1
    }else if (tableView.tag==2) {
        //Do what ever you want with table having tag =2
    }
}
```

Comment: in which tableview's delegate i should put it, i mean, i do have an another tableview embdedded inside cells of tableView of MainTableVC

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 // NSLog(@"user selected %@",[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
NSString *listOfFacebookIDs = @"";
NSArray *indexPathArray = [self.mTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
for(NSIndexPath *index in indexPathArray){
    //Assuming that 'idFriends' is an array you've made containing the id's (and in the same order as your tableview)
    //Otherwise embed the ID as a property of a custom tableViewCell and access directly from the cell
    //Also assuming you only have one section inside your tableview
    NSString *fbID = [dataArray objectAtIndex:index.row];
    if([indexPathArray lastObject]!=index){
        listOfFacebookIDs = [listOfFacebookIDs stringByAppendingString:[fbID stringByAppendingString:@", "]];
    }else{
        listOfFacebookIDs = [listOfFacebookIDs stringByAppendingString:fbID];
    }
}
  NSLog(@"Your comma separated string is %@",listOfFacebookIDs);
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"user de-selected %@",[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}
```

[image]